# Can a drop down parameter skipped to get the output?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

Below is my requirement.

"   All reports must have a *LIST* option.  The option must include a “no list” selection as well as a DISTINCT list of *“LISTName”* from the *“LISTS”* table.  See example below.  If **“no list”** is selected by the user the report should output the full record set.  If the full record set is more than one million rows we need to require that a filter or *LIST* is used".

Here LIST is the parameter.It does not have full values of the main table.It has only few particular values.Can we give a **no list** option so that it skips and gives all values from main query???

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query to dynamically populate the available values for your parameter. Then, in your main query, you can check for the "no list" option.

First, add a dataset to the report. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT distinct LISTName
FROM LIST
WHERE <my conditions>
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'No List' as LISTNAME
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(LISTName)
    FROM LIST
    WHERE <my conditions>
    ) < 1000000
```

In your parameter properties, set the Available Values to use this dataset.

Next, in your main dataset you'll need to update the `WHERE` clause. It would look something like this:

```
WHERE (@LIST_Param = 'No List' or @LIST_Param = LISTName)
```

Comment: Hi Steven,I tried using your answer but I couldn't find 'No List' option in the drop down list

Comment: @KrishDev Did you update the query AND set the parameter to use that dataset for the Available Values?

Comment: Yeah I updated the query.I saw 'no list' in the list but it executes with no output values

Comment: @KrishDev do you get results if you pass 'No List' to your main query in SSMS?

Comment: No.I did not get any output

Comment: @KrishDev So something is wrong with your SQL statement. Would you mind sharing what you have so far?

Comment: It is just giving output when actual value is selected and no output when 'No List' is selected

Answer (score 0):

I know this is minor but Steven White's solution would need to be slightly to include distinct count:

```
COUNT (DISTINCT LISTName)
```

You would also want a non-clustered index on LISTName to support the DISTINCT operators in the query. Using this sample data:

```
-- Sample data
CREATE TABLE #LIST (LISTName varchar(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT #LIST 
SELECT TOP (100) LEFT(newid(), 8)
FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

-- You will probably want LISTName to be indexed
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_LISTName ON #LIST(LISTName);
```

The solution would look like this:

```
DECLARE @LIST_Param varchar(8) = 'No List';

SELECT LISTName 
FROM 
(
  SELECT distinct LISTName, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LISTName) FROM #LIST) 
  FROM #LIST
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'No List'
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LISTName) FROM #LIST) < 1000000
) Distinct_LISTName
WHERE (@LIST_Param = 'No List' or @LIST_Param = LISTName);
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
DECLARE @LIST_Param varchar(8) = 'No List'; --'CFA647F7';

WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT LISTName, c = COUNT(*)
  FROM #LIST
  WHERE (@LIST_Param = 'No List' or @LIST_Param = LISTName)
  GROUP BY LISTName
),
c AS (SELECT s = SUM(c) FROM x)
SELECT LISTName
FROM x CROSS JOIN c
WHERE s < 1000000;
```